# Bluetooth headset stops working on screenlock and after restart on 22.04.2

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, lock-screen, reboot

I've updated the system this morning and noticed that my Bluetooth headset stops working upon restart or screenlock on Ubuntu 22.04.2 with Gnome 42.5.
To fix this I have to go Settings > Sound and switch Output Device between HDMI and Headset (sometimes couple of times).

Didn't have this problem with 22.04 until now.

Anyone else had experienced anything like that?